# Bizarre behavior trying to store a deque in a Shelve

Tags: python, shelve

I will let the following terminal session speak for itself:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> s = shelve.open('TestShelve')
>>> from collections import deque
>>> s['store'] = deque()
>>> d = s['store']
>>> print s['store']
deque([])
>>> print d
deque([])
>>> s['store'].appendleft('Teststr')
>>> d.appendleft('Teststr')
>>> print s['store']
deque([])
>>> print d
deque(['Teststr'])
```

Shouldn't `d` and `s['store']` point to the same object? Why does `appendleft` work on `d` but not on `s['store']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out they're not the same so any operations you perform on them won't match:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> s = shelve.open('TestShelve')
>>> from collections import deque
>>> s['store'] = deque()
>>> d = s['store']
>>> id(s['store'])
27439296
>>> id(d)
27439184
```

To modify items as you coded, you need to pass the parameter `writeback=True`:

```
s = shelve.open('TestShelve', writeback=True)
```

See the documentation:

> If the writeback parameter is True, the object will hold a cache of
>   all entries accessed and write them back to the dict at sync and close
>   times. This allows natural operations on mutable entries, but can
>   consume much more memory and make sync and close take a long time.

You can also do it with `writeback=False` but then you need to write the code exactly as in the provided example:

```
# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it
```

Comment: So assigning a variable to an entry of a Shelve automatically creates a copy. Why can I not append to the deque stored in the Shelve?

Comment: @dpitch40: I have updated the answer with an explanation on how to modify items in a Shelve.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

`shelve` is `pickle`ing (serializing) the object. Of necessity, this makes a copy. So, the objects you get back from `shelve` won't have the same identity as the ones you put in, though they will be equivalent.

If it's important, you could write a `deque` subclass that automatically re-shelves itself whenever it's modified, although this would probably have poor performance in many use cases.